# Solve the zero by Jacobi Method:$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}2& 1\\ 1&2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, jacobian

> Solve by Jacobi Method $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\  1 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\  y \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
> 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with starting point $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$

I don't want see the complete solution (it would be too long anyway, probably). But rather the scheme how it is done, the beginning.

So how do you start? You usually change this to a system of equation form but it doesn't seem to work in this case because we have $f(x,y)$

Would I be allowed to write it like that?

$$2x+y-1=0$$

$$x+2y=0$$

Now I would form the first equation to $x$ and the second equation to $y$:

$$x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}y$$

$$y=-\frac{1}{2}x$$

And then continue...? Is that correct?

Comment: Solve **what**?  You give a formula but I see no equation or problem to be "solved".  Did you mean $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?  Perhaps you were introduced to the "Jacobi method" as a method of solving equations of the form f(x,y)= 0?

Comment: @user247327 The zero of a function yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct.  Form iterations from the two equations and then approximate $(x,  y)$ using $x_0=0$ and $y_0=0$ as initial values.